# Computer doesn't recognize Android device after getting charge port replaced

Tags: hardware, usb-debugging

I recently took my Samsung Galaxy 2 to a place that sells phones and services and also repairs them.  I took it there because my charge port was not charging anymore so he said he could replace it. However, now it will not even connect to the computer at all. Any computer, doesn't matter. I have tried everything.

Since it doesn't respond to my computer or any computer, can I still root my phone?  And also, is it even possible for the port he put on to not do data transfer, only charge?

Comment: As indicated by Dan's answer: Bring it back to that service point, explain your issue, and have the service tech check whether thy "forgot" to solder some connections. They should do so for free, as they caused the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Most rooting techniques require you to connect the phone to a PC via USB in order to unlock the bootloader, so you won't be able to root the phone this way without a working USB port. Some phones have security vulnerabilities which allow you to root the phone from an app (such as Framaroot), but this only applies to specific phones and specific firmware versions which have such a bug.

It's certainly possible for a port to only charge and not transfer data. In a USB port, there are two data pins, a +5V power pin, and ground. If either of the two data pins are broken or not connected properly, you can still transfer power over the power connection, but no data can be transferred. Most likely these pins weren't soldered correctly when your new USB port was added.